# Weight Attribute Not Working

Tags: android

I'm using a TAB Host, with 5 Activities that i can switch via tabs, When i run Activities solo in a separate application each weight attributes works fine wit. But When i Run them in a TAB Host weight attribute does not work. Why is it so. What i had to do say if i had to divide it my current application in 1:2:3 ratio with in a tab host?

For just Test purpose i created two Linear layouts 1:1 ratio in 1 activity when i run them as if in a tab hots weight does not work while in a simple application it works?? what's wrong.

**xml tabhost activity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
           />

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
            android:background="@color/darkblue_bottombar"
            android:paddingBottom="1sp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="200sp"
            android:paddingRight="200sp"></TabWidget>

          </RelativeLayout>

</TabHost>
```

**tab2 xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/Dialog_done_grey"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="CHECK4"
            android:textSize="18dip" />
    </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/blue_header"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="CHECK5"
            android:textSize="18dip" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In 
change attribute height to fill_parent

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
       />
```